# Git cloning with ssh not possible

Tags: git, github, ssh

Solved: My dad reset our routers settings (Which according to him he didn't even change in the first place. He thinks an update must have changed them) and now it works

So for some reason, I can't pull from my git repos anymore. I have the remotes as ssh keys. I already deleted them and added new keys to my GitHub account.

It's the only ssh key I have so it definitely can't pick the wrong private key. with a simple ssh command, I can connect to GitHub, verifying that it works but when I try to pull or clone a repo I get a

`fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

I also tried the whole thing with `eval $(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add` but still doesn't work

This is the whole output I'm getting when trying to clone something

```
❯ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@github.com:OverloaderV/Web-Praktikum.git
Cloning into 'Web-Praktikum'...
OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/lukas/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/lukas/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-a0da6a28
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-a0da6a28
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXHdpn0r/agent.5543'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:H5JDypggyIaxAREi4UWYhGooW09RafD9qMw4oyJGxEY explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:H5JDypggyIaxAREi4UWYhGooW09RafD9qMw4oyJGxEY explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:H5JDypggyIaxAREi4UWYhGooW09RafD9qMw4oyJGxEY explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:H5JDypggyIaxAREi4UWYhGooW09RafD9qMw4oyJGxEY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:H5JDypggyIaxAREi4UWYhGooW09RafD9qMw4oyJGxEY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.3]:22) using "publickey".
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/lukas/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env I3SOCK
debug3: Ignored env GIT_SSH_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env DOTNET_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug1: channel 0: setting env GIT_PROTOCOL = "version=2"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env MOTD_SHOWN
debug3: Ignored env GIT_EXEC_PATH
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LANG
debug3: Ignored env ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE
debug3: Ignored env STARSHIP_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR
debug3: Ignored env STARSHIP_SESSION_KEY
debug3: Ignored env ALACRITTY_SOCKET
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_HOME
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env BROWSER
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env ALACRITTY_LOG
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env ALACRITTY_WINDOW_ID
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'OverloaderV/Web-Praktikum.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x01/0x00)

Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 3220, received 2528 bytes, in 780.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4.1, received 3.2
debug1: Exit status -1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Does `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@github.com:OverloaderV/Web-Praktikum.git` reveal anything?

Comment: I replaced the output with 1 -v with the output with 3 -v. It takes ages to fail, feels like timing out to me @phd

Comment: That strange; everything else works, but timeout at the end? At what line ssh was hanging most?

Comment: Cant try out right now since im not home. i noticed it only happens in my home network but according to my dad there aren't any proxies or firewalls runnin

Comment: Its hanging at `debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768`

Answer (score 0):

You've successfully authenticated as someone who does not have access to `OverloaderV/Web-Praktikum.git`.  Use `ssh -T git@github.com` to have GitHub tell who you they believe you are.

The public key that you sent first, which was accepted, was that associated with `/home/lukas/.ssh/id_rsa`.  Note that GitHub have a table (stored in their servers) that maps that public key, whatever its data are, to a user name, and that's who they think you are.

If you need to authenticate using a *different* public key, so that you authenticate as someone else, consider augmenting your `.ssh/config` file so that you list specific public keys with the `IdentitiesOnly yes` option to control the set of keys offered and their order.  You're using an ssh agent, and your ssh is currently offering keys in the order specified by the agent.

Comment: I only have one key. ANd the owner of the public key on github is the owner of the repo. When I do the `ssh -T` it thells me im that user

Comment: In that case, check to make sure that the same user has permission to access that repository (GitHub in general will allow you to deny yourself permission, so that's a possibility).

Comment: I definitely do have permission. As I noted in another comment, it seems to be a network issue, in my Uni it works

Comment: Your ssh output above ends with `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` and `Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` That means you *don't* have permission (to `Sending command: git-upload-pack 'OverloaderV/Web-Praktikum.git'` specifically).

Comment: This *could* be a networking issue if someone is trapping traffic that is supposedly going to github.com and redirecting it to somewhere else. That seems ... unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: I do have acces permissions. I double and tripple checked at github.

Comment: And yet, right there in your ssh output is a message from the host you called up saying that you *don't* have access permissions. At this point this is something to resolve by contacting GitHub support.

Comment: Its not only github. it's also gitlab. so github support probably won't help. And it works if I clone while I'm not in my home network